# Isolating a function when data is mapped in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have data being mapped as a repeater. But I need to isolate the opening function (It's an accordion). I'm still learning my way through React. Basically, the accordions load with the state for `open: false` Once the ListItem is clicked, the `HandleClick` function toggles the state to `open: true`. A simple concept, I just need to isolate it so that it works independently. Whereas right now they all open and close at the same time.

Here is the state in a constructor and function

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        open: true,
    };
}

handleClick = () => { this.setState({ open: !this.state.open }); };
```

Here is my mapping script in ReactJS

```
{LicenseItems.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
        <ListItem 
            divider 
            button
            onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ListItemText primary={<CMLabel>{item.accordion_name}</CMLabel>}/>
        </ListItem> 
        <Collapse
            in={!this.state.open} 
            timeout="auto" 
            unmountOnExit>
            {item.content}
        </Collapse> 
    </div>
))}
```

The `in` dictates whether it is open or not per MaterialUI-Next

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very pretty, but something like this should work:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        open: {},
    };
}
handleClick = (idx) => {
  this.setState(state => ({open: { [idx]: !state.open[idx]} }))
}

// in render
{LicenseItems.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
        <ListItem 
            divider 
            button
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}>
            <ListItemText primary={<CMLabel>{item.accordion_name}</CMLabel>}/>
        </ListItem> 
        <Collapse
            in={!this.state.open[index]} 
            timeout="auto" 
            unmountOnExit>
            {item.content}
        </Collapse> 
    </div>
))}
```

It would be better to create separate Components for that, which have their own `open` state.

Comment: This works great! One minor modification on the ! operator in the in property but as soon as I removed it, it worked great! Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You should create two components for that:

Accordions.js

```
import React from 'react'

import Accordion from './Accordion'

const Accordions = props => {
  return (
    props.LicenseItems.map((item, index) => (
      <Accordion key={index} item={item} />
    ))
  );
}

export default Accordions;
```

Accordion.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Accordion extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        open: true,
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => { this.setState({ open: !this.state.open }); };

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <ListItem 
            divider 
            button
            onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <ListItemText primary={<CMLabel>{this.props.item.accordion_name}</CMLabel>}/>
        </ListItem> 
        <Collapse
            in={!this.state.open} 
            timeout="auto" 
            unmountOnExit>
            {this.props.item.content}
        </Collapse> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Accordion;
```